# How to deserialize this xml doc into list

Tags: c#

In app a get a response from vk server with information about user's playlist in xml. App throw `InvalidOperationexception` here

```
var result = (PlayList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

DTOs:

```
public class PlayList
{
    [XmlElement("audio")]
    public List<Song> Audio { get; set; }

    public PlayList()
    {
        Audio = new List<Song>();
    }
}

public class Song
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName ="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [XmlElement(ElementName ="genre_id")]
    public int Genre_id { get; set; }``
}
```

But my code work when I delete this 3 lines from xmlfile

```
<response> 
<count>156</count> 
... 
<response>
and <items list="true">  ->  <items>
```

What I must change in my code to make it work?

```
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayList), new XmlRootAttribute("items"));
  using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
  using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
  {
      var result = (PlayList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      Console.WriteLine(result.Audio[1].Title);
  }
```

And this is an example of xml.
How do I Deserialize this XML document?

```
var xml =
@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<count>156</count>
<items list="true">
<audio>
  <id>456239034</id>
  <owner_id>181216176</owner_id>
  <artist>Oh Wonder</artist>
  <title>Technicolour Beat</title>
  <duration>179</duration>
  <date>1465249779</date>
  <url>http://cs613222.vk.me/u285269348/audios/4ae051b98797.mp3?extra=MS3dvwutPkFx7k8rQdV3Szuh7cSwLkRcS_KpPbO9DXviMFLNNgkDAmZFWdIueioL3dDgdPUc7rch0V81KgOHYaTTSampaRcljxrJcytJYImZssivVP7DigKdcxaLoALeUatAhuHk5gXQ7TY</url>
  <lyrics_id>235824304</lyrics_id>
  <genre_id>1001</genre_id>
</audio>
<audio>
  <id>456239033</id>
  <owner_id>181216176</owner_id>
  <artist>Mikky Ekko</artist>
  <title>We Must Be Killers (Волчонок / Teen Wolf / 2х08) </title>
  <duration>195</duration>
  <date>1465249755</date>
  <url>http://cs521610.vk.me/u14558277/audios/c2daca7b2b6f.mp3?extra=z9VPdKf6v-    n7zkIfZ_6ej-RZSjlIjAr_qYmVp4F-zI1Z3ZXgVtOUElovlOiSOgSuKbFC0e0ahac8XU-AxNtfEYYPe5gcejSotr84mHi0LQ2L-b0BPWP2cYn5Yy44YN4FLPNKq0Ow8vMKFn0</url>
  <lyrics_id>26311225</lyrics_id>
</audio>
</items>
</response>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let it know its an array, I think using `typeof(PlayList[])` instead of `typeof(PlayList)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip unnecessary nodes with the `XmlReader`.

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("items");

    var result = (PlayList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```